# How to set ContentType in s3.Object using boto3 and would it affect processing in lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

how can i set content type to image/jpeg format on the file the file, I am uploading using

```
s3.Object(bucket_name, file_name).put(Body=open(full_path,'rb'))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.put), use the `ContentType` keyword argument:

```py
with open(full_path, 'rb') as f:
    s3.Object(bucket_name, file_name).put(Body=f, ContentType='image/jpeg')
```